# Search full text in mongodb

Tags: php, mongodb

```
db.collection.createIndex({"type_name":"text"});
db.collection.find();
```

Outputs:

```
{ "type_id" : "10735", "type_name" : "Tycho" }

{ "type_id" : "1550", "type_name" : "Trina" }

{ "type_id" : "12925", "type_name" : "Tiffany" }

{ "type_id" : "1637", "type_name" : "The Wombats" }

{ "type_id" : "11470", "type_name" : "The Wanted" }
```

Using:

```
db.collection.find({'$text':{'$search':"The Wombats"}})
```

Outputs:

```
{ "type_id" : "1637", "type_name" : "The Wombats" }
```

Using:

```
db.collection.find({'$text':{'$search':"Wombats"}});
```

Outputs:

```
{ "type_id" : "1637", "type_name" : "The Wombats" }
```

But when I try :

```
db.collection.find({'$text':{'$search':"The"}});
```

Output:

```
0
```

I am expecting a different output, what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Mongodb has some stop words for $text operator.

**Stop Words**

The $text operator ignores language-specific stop words, such as **the** and **and** in English.

Since you are using one of the stop word, in the query `db.collection.find({'$text':{'$search':"The"}})` and hence it is not returning any results.

References:

https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/query/text/#op._S_text

https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/query/text/#match-operation

Comment: but when i try this $regex = new MongoRegex("/^".the."^/"."/i");
   $artistNmaeRenge=array('type_name'=> $regex); it this work

Comment: @dev -  Yes it should work, because you are not using $text-https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/ and you have used $regex in your new query(moreover there is no stopwords for $regex it is only applicable for $text)

Answer (score 0):

But when i am try this

$regex = new MongoRegex("/^".the."^/"."/i");

$artistNmaeRenge=array('type_name'=> $regex);
it's working